# Is there a way to detect the player name a "/testfor" command has detected?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Simply put I want to make a minigame on my server. where when a player reaches 15 kills the game is over and the player who got the 15 kills wins. I can detect and send a pulse when "A" player reaches 15 but I cannot display the player who won/ detect even who won. the command I'm using to detect when someone reaches 15 kills is here `testfor @a[r=400,score_killCount_min=15]` {using scoreboard obj I set up a kill counter.} I basically want to tell who the player who has won is and teleport him.

Answer (score 3):

What is stopping you from just doing this?:

```
/tp @a[r=400,score_killCount_min=15] <destination>
```

You could then easily detect who won, because that person will be exactly at the place where you teleported him/her

Or this in newer versions:

```
/tp @a[distance=..400,scores={killCount=15..}] <destination>
```

In newer versions you can then use this command to tell who won:

```
/execute positioned <destination> run say @a[distance=..1] won
```